# Extracting complete lines from a data stream

Tags: c#, unit-testing, extension-methods

When reading from the Console, it's very easy to get a complete line, you simply call `Console.Readline`.

When reading from a `TCPClient` there isn't an equivalent function.  You can either read a byte at a time, or read a block (up to a maximum size) in which case an arbitrary amount of data will be returned depending how the network behaved.

In order to simplify line extraction I've written a `LineBuffer` class.  It has an `Append` method that allows new blocks of data to be added to the buffer.  Whenever a complete line is received, the action supplied via the constructor is called.

The `LineBuffer` class:

```
using System;
using System.Text;

namespace MudCore.Connection
{
    public class LineBuffer
    {
        private readonly Action<string> _onLineFound;
        private readonly StringBuilder _currentLine;

        public LineBuffer(Action<string> onLineFound)
        {
            _onLineFound = onLineFound;
            _currentLine = new StringBuilder();
        }

        public void Append(string input)
        {
            if (input == null) return;

            while (input.Contains("\n"))
            {
                var indexOfNewLine = input.IndexOf('\n');
                var left = input.Substring(0, indexOfNewLine);
                _currentLine.Append(left);

                var line = _currentLine.Replace("\r","").ToString();

                _currentLine.Clear();
                if (indexOfNewLine != input.Length - 1)
                {
                    input = input.Substring(indexOfNewLine + 1);
                }
                else
                {
                    input = string.Empty;
                }

                _onLineFound.Invoke(line);
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
            {
                _currentLine.Append(input);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Some unit tests:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;

using NUnit.Framework;

using MudCore.Connection;
using MudCoreTests.Helpers;

namespace MudCoreTests.Connection
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class LineBufferTests
    {
        [Test]
        public void AppendingEmptyStringDoesNothing()
        {
            int callCount = 0;
            LineBuffer buffer = new LineBuffer((extractedLine) => { callCount++; });

            buffer.Append("");

            Assert.AreEqual(0, callCount);
        }

        [Test]
        public void AppendingNullStringDoesNothing()
        {
            int callCount = 0;
            LineBuffer buffer = new LineBuffer((extractedLine) => { callCount++; });

            buffer.Append(null);

            Assert.AreEqual(0, callCount);
        }

        [TestCase("\r\n")]
        [TestCase("\n")]
        public void SingleLineIsExtractedMinusEndOfLine(string endOfLine)
        {
            int callCount = 0;
            string foundLine = String.Empty;
            string lineToAppend = "This is a line";

            LineBuffer buffer = new LineBuffer((extractedLine) => { foundLine = extractedLine; callCount++; });

            buffer.Append(lineToAppend + endOfLine);

            Assert.AreEqual(1, callCount);
            Assert.AreEqual(lineToAppend, foundLine);
        }

        [TestCaseSource("ReceivedBufferTestCases")]
        public void MultipleLinesAreIdentifiedFromMultipleAppends(Queue<string> receivedData, Queue<string> expectedLines, string scenarioName)
        {
            var expectedCount = expectedLines.Count;
            var callCount = 0;

            LineBuffer buffer = new LineBuffer((extractedLine) => {
                var expectedLine = expectedLines.Dequeue();
                Assert.AreEqual(expectedLine, extractedLine, $"Expected: '{expectedLine}' but go '{extractedLine}' during scenario {scenarioName}");
                callCount++;
            });

            while (receivedData.Count > 0)
            {
                buffer.Append(receivedData.Dequeue());
            }

            Assert.AreEqual(expectedCount, callCount, $"Incorrect number of lines extracted, expected {expectedCount}, but was {callCount} during scenario {scenarioName}");
        }

        public static IEnumerable ReceivedBufferTestCases
        {
            get {
                yield return new TestCaseData(new Queue<string> { "One\n", "Two\n", "Three\n" },
                                              new Queue<string> { "One", "Two", "Three" },
                                              "Simple Complete Lines");
                yield return new TestCaseData(new Queue<string> { "One\r\n", "Two\r\n", "Three\r\n" },
                                              new Queue<string> { "One", "Two", "Three" },
                                              "Simple Complete Lines with \\r\\n");
                yield return new TestCaseData(new Queue<string> { "On", "e\n", "Two\n", "Three\n" },
                                              new Queue<string> { "One", "Two", "Three" },
                                              "Line split across two buffers");
                yield return new TestCaseData(new Queue<string> { "One\r", "\nT", "wo\n", "Three\n" },
                                              new Queue<string> { "One", "Two", "Three" },
                                              "Line split cr/lf across two buffers");
                yield return new TestCaseData(new Queue<string> { "One\r\nTwo\nThree\n" },
                                              new Queue<string> { "One", "Two", "Three" },
                                              "All data from one buffer");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the unit tests, I've made use of the collection initializer.  Since `Queue<T>` doesn't support this, I've also created an extension method to make the tests easier to write.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace MudCoreTests.Helpers
{
    public static class QueueExtensions
    {
        static public void Add<T>(this Queue<T> q, T item)
        {
            q.Enqueue(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Any feedback is welcome.  Is there any built-in functionality that does something similar that I haven't come across yet? Is the code readable? Is the extension method a bad idea?

If you need more context for where the class fits, the project is currently used [here](https://github.com/forsvarir/Mud).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some alternatives that are built in, for example in the simplest form combine a [`NetworkStream`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream(v=vs.110).aspx) with [`StreamReader`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
using (var netStream = new NetworkStream(tcpClient.Client))
using (var reader = new StreamReader(netStream))
{
    var line = reader.ReadLine();
}
```

Which is unbuffered, if you want to add buffering in, just use a [`BufferedStream`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.bufferedstream(v=vs.110).aspx) in the middle:

```
using (var netStream = new NetworkStream(tcpClient.Client))
using (var bufferStream = new BufferedStream(netStream))
using (var reader = new StreamReader(bufferStream))
{
    var line = reader.ReadLine();
}
```

These are pretty high performance because they operate at a lower level. Ideally you'd want to ditch the `TcpClient` and go direct with a `Socket` for best performance, but `TcpClient.Client` gives direct access to the underlying socket.

Comment: This is a great example how decorators can be neatly combined to utilize the power of each of them and one rarely can see how three of them can work at the same time ;-)

Comment: I could have done with this answer over here: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/147606/4203 .  I'm doing async reads, so it's a bit more convoluted, however it does seem to work with a combination of `TcpClient.GetStream()` and `StreamReader.ReadLineAsync().ContinueWith(...)`.  Thanks.